# AWS ECS task failing - invalid character '}' looking for beginning of object key string

Tags: json, amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs, aws-fargate

I am trying to create an AWS ECS task through Terraform. Everything gets applied successfully. However, on ECS side, the task fails to start. I've already validated my json on [jsonlint.com](https://jsonlint.com) and it looks good.

This is the complete error:

```
Task stopped at: 2023-08-17T18:34:10.304Z
ResourceInitializationError: unable to pull secrets or registry auth: execution resource retrieval failed: unable to retrieve secret from asm: service call has been retried 1 time(s): invalid character '}' looking for beginning of object key string
```

I've tried all the solutions I found but none worked for me.

This is my json:

```
    {
    "taskDefinitionArn": "arn:aws:ecs:ca-central-1:123:task-definition/abc-task-def:6",
    "containerDefinitions": [
        {
            "name": "abc-container",
            "image": "123.dkr.ecr.ca-central-1.amazonaws.com/gam-abc-kinesis-reader:latest",
            "cpu": 10,
            "memory": 1024,
            "portMappings": [
                {
                    "containerPort": 8080,
                    "hostPort": 8080,
                    "protocol": "tcp"
                }
            ],
            "essential": true,
            "environment": [
                {
                    "name": "ENV",
                    "value": "dev"
                }
            ],
            "mountPoints": [],
            "volumesFrom": [],
            "secrets": [
                {
                    "name": "S3_BUCKET_NAME",
                    "valueFrom": "arn:aws:secretsmanager:ca-central-1:123:secret:abc/S3_BUCKET_NAME-PgaYtE:S3_BUCKET_NAME::"
                },
                {
                    "name": "S3_SECRET_KEY",
                    "valueFrom": "arn:aws:secretsmanager:ca-central-1:123:secret:abc/S3_SECRET_KEY-XPedks:S3_SECRET_KEY::"
                },
                {
                    "name": "S3_ACCESS_KEY",
                    "valueFrom": "arn:aws:secretsmanager:ca-central-1:123:secret:abc/S3_ACCESS_KEY-j2JuEy:S3_ACCESS_KEY::"
                },
                {
                    "name": "KINESIS_ACCESS_KEY",
                    "valueFrom": "arn:aws:secretsmanager:ca-central-1:123:secret:abc/KINESIS_ACCESS_KEY-xkAnDG:KINESIS_ACCESS_KEY::"
                },
                {
                    "name": "KINESIS_SECRET_KEY",
                    "valueFrom": "arn:aws:secretsmanager:ca-central-1:123:secret:abc/KINESIS_SECRET_KEY-4arK3C:KINESIS_SECRET_KEY::"
                }
            ],
            "logConfiguration": {
                "logDriver": "awslogs",
                "options": {
                    "awslogs-group": "abc-logs",
                    "awslogs-region": "ca-central-1",
                    "awslogs-stream-prefix": "abc"
                }
            }
        }
    ],
    "family": "abc-task-def",
    "executionRoleArn": "arn:aws:iam::123:role/abc-ecs_task_exec_role",
    "networkMode": "awsvpc",
    "revision": 6,
    "volumes": [],
    "status": "ACTIVE",
    "requiresAttributes": [
        {
            "name": "com.amazonaws.ecs.capability.logging-driver.awslogs"
        },
        {
            "name": "ecs.capability.execution-role-awslogs"
        },
        {
            "name": "com.amazonaws.ecs.capability.ecr-auth"
        },
        {
            "name": "com.amazonaws.ecs.capability.docker-remote-api.1.19"
        },
        {
            "name": "ecs.capability.secrets.asm.environment-variables"
        },
        {
            "name": "ecs.capability.execution-role-ecr-pull"
        },
        {
            "name": "com.amazonaws.ecs.capability.docker-remote-api.1.18"
        },
        {
            "name": "ecs.capability.task-eni"
        }
    ],
    "placementConstraints": [],
    "compatibilities": [
        "EC2",
        "FARGATE"
    ],
    "requiresCompatibilities": [
        "FARGATE"
    ],
    "cpu": "256",
    "memory": "1024",
    "registeredAt": "2023-08-17T18:32:55.815Z",
    "registeredBy": "arn:aws:sts::123:assumed-role/AWSReservedSSO_PowerAdmin_01c43d6b605087cf/ms@test.com",
    "tags": [
        {
            "key": "Project",
            "value": "abc"
        },
        {
            "key": "Owner",
            "value": "ms@test.com"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Does any of your secret key contains } character in it?

Comment: The value of your secret in AWS Secrets Manager is not value JSON.

Comment: "unable to retrieve secret from asm: [...]  invalid character '}' looking for beginning of object key string" check that secret and see if it's valid json